# Cannot save files info to db

Tags: angularjs, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload, ng-file-upload

I am using [ng-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/issues/2044) and ASP MVC and my input saves multiple files. The files are successfully saving in the folder path specified in the controller but the file info (id, name, path and recipeId) is not saving to db.

After the controller process it returns `null` to the view.

**File.cs**

```
public class File
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Name cannot be longer than 30 characters.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Path")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Path cannot be longer than 30 characters.")]
    public string Path { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Recipe")]
    public int RecipeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Recipe Recipe { get; set; }
}
```

**Angular**

```
$scope.SelectedFiles = files;
if ($scope.SelectedFiles && $scope.SelectedFiles.length) {
    Upload.upload({
        url: '/Files/Upload/',
        data: {
            files: $scope.SelectedFiles,
            RecipeId: $scope.recipeID
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.Result = response.data;
        });
    }, function (response) {
        if (response.status > 0) {
            var errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
            alert(errorMsg);
        } else {
            console.log(response.data);
        }
    }, function (evt) {
        $scope.Progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
    });
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ContentResult  Upload(File vm)
{
    string path = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/");
    int RecipeId = vm.RecipeId;
    foreach (string key in Request.Files)
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase postedFile = Request.Files[key];
        postedFile.SaveAs(path + postedFile.FileName);

        File recipefile = new File();
        recipefile.Name = postedFile.FileName; 
        recipefile.Path = path; 
        recipefile.RecipeId = RecipeId; 
        db.Files.Add(recipefile);
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
    return Content("Success");
}
```

I get the following error.

```
System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146232032
  Message=Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.
  Source=FAC Recipes
  StackTrace:
       at FACRecipes.Controllers.FilesController.Upload(File vm) in ...Controllers\FilesController.cs:line 52
       at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
       at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: you should save changes after adding file to db.

Comment: @NTP Oh I forgot to add. Thanks! After I added save changes it returned this error. `System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException was unhandled by user code`

Comment: You are getting that error because either you are missing a required field or your data is in wrong format.

Comment: @NTP I don't know what's causing it because I don't have any required in my `File.cs`. I posted that error above.

Comment: can you post message inside EntityValidationErrors

Comment: @NTP I posted the error above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the `async Task` and `await db.SaveChangesAsync();` so I keep getting the validation error. The problem was that I set the `StringLength` to `30` in `File.cs` so I increased the `StringLength` and it worked! Thanks Everyone!

```
public class File
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    [StringLength(500)
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Path")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Path { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Recipe")]
    public int RecipeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Recipe Recipe { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i will suggest you to add a try catch block to your code and then 
Make your catch block like this it will help you to find the actual error

```
   catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
            {
                Exception raise = dbEx;
                foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        string message = string.Format("{0}:{1}",
                            validationErrors.Entry.Entity.ToString(),
                            validationError.ErrorMessage);
                        // raise a new exception nesting
                        // the current instance as InnerException
                        raise = new InvalidOperationException(message, raise);
                    }
                }
                throw dbEx;
            }
```

Comment: It still throws the same error so I added `async Task` and `await db.SaveChangesAsync();` and It stopped throwing the validationErrors but the info still doesn't get save in db.